# What is the implication of 东鄙？

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is 东鄙 something like, " the barbaric East"? More generally, not a place a gentleman would choose to visit? Or was it actually the name of a city or town or region?

```
1. 齐侯阳虎，将**东**之。《左传·定公九年》
2. 仲子曰：“······今无故而废之，是专黜诸侯，而以难犯不祥也。君必悔之。”公曰：“在我而已。”遂**东**太子光。《左传·襄公十九年》
```

In 1. 东：囚禁于东鄙
In 2. 东：徙······于东鄙

Comment: links to pdf of 周髀算經, some of them might be “blocked”  [周髀算經・卷上 乾隆御覽本](https://archive.org/details/06081595.cn)

[周髀算經・卷下 乾隆御覽本](https://archive.org/details/06081596.cn)

Comment: [周髀算經圖解](https://archive.org/details/shuhisankeizukai158800)

[周髀算經・周髀算經音義](https://id.lib.harvard.edu/curiosity/chinese-rare-books/49-990079025730203941_FHCL:25866106)

[周髀算経](https://www.digital.archives.go.jp/DAS/meta/listPhoto?LANG=default&BID=F1000000000000101270&ID=&TYPE=)

[周髀算経国字解](https://www.wul.waseda.ac.jp/kotenseki/html/ni05/ni05_00731/index.html)

Comment: are you sure you want to read mathematics in classical chinese? it’s quite difficult lah 

Comment: Sorry, I meant, if you knew of a link to a good Modern Chinese version! I am neither good at Chinese nor Mathematics, not to mention Classical Chinese!

Comment: modern chinese version? no lah 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“東鄙”, i would interpret it as “eastern region”

one of the significance evidence is in [傳・昭公五年](https://ctext.org/chun-qiu-zuo-zhuan/zhao-gong-wu-nian/zh?searchu=%E6%9D%B1%E9%84%99&searchmode=showall#result):

> 豎牛取**東鄙**三十邑・以與南遺

that, “東鄙” is an entity bigger than a town / city “邑”

then the book [太平御覽・卷一百五十七](https://archive.org/details/06065146.cn/page/n69/mode/1up) mentioned:

> 周書曰・郊田・方六百里・因四土爲方千里・分以百縣・縣有四郡・郡有**鄙**・**鄙**不過百室・以便野事

> 周禮・地官・遂人曰・五家爲鄰・五鄰爲里・四里爲鄼・五鄼爲**鄙**・五**鄙**爲縣・五縣爲遂

that 鄙 is one of the administrative entity, less than a hundred houses (鄙不過百室), or, one fifth of a county (五鄙爲縣)

last, in the verse in 傳・定公九年

> 齊侯執陽虎，將東之

my brief reading , and understanding is: “陽虎” tried to coup in the nation “魯”, failed, escaped to the nation “齊”; was captured.

after the remonstration by “鮑文子”, the ruler “齊侯” want to send “陽虎” eastward (back to the nation “魯”)

that the “東” is not related to “東鄙”

then, the verse in [傳・襄公十九年](https://ctext.org/chun-qiu-zuo-zhuan/xiang-gong-shi-jiu-nian/zh?searchu=%E5%9C%A8%E6%88%91%E8%80%8C%E5%B7%B2%EF%BC%8C%E9%81%82%E6%9D%B1%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%90%E5%85%89&searchmode=showall#result) is

> 在我而已，遂東大子光

well, read it as “it’s my decision (在我而已), therefore (遂) [relocate] eastward (東) the [former] crown prince (大子 —> 太子) who named “光”

frankly, both example quoted are, err . . . . i’ve difficulties to relate it to “東鄙”

have fun :)

Comment: Thanks! My source is a linguistics book I am reading from 神家煊。Sorry if the author has not given a true account of the old Chinese! If I have your attention: could you give me a good link 周髀算经？ He was a Chinese Pythagoras with very interesting mathematical ideas based on 90° triangles!

Answer (score 2):

In 《左传》 东鄙 is the eastern bordering regions. Sometimes it refers to the eastern bordering cities/towns (邊邑). It's not their name but a general reference.

It's also not barbaric. Barbaric is normally 化外之地, mostly referring to 夷狄

There's no tradition that 君子 would not choose to visit 鄙. In that period, 鄙 is often entitled （分封） to the noblemen of lower ranks.

Those being said, 鄙 is far away from the center of politics. Its negative implications have further developed in later periods.

Comment: I live in 东鄙：江苏南京！It doesn't seem too barbaric! :)

Answer (score 1):

Both passages are from a commentary book [Zuo Zhuan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuo_Zhuan) composed as of the 4th century BC about history between the 8th and the 5th century BC, during which the fast east region of China was enfeoffed to nobility who were not direct offspring of the king's ancestor and thus considered not as noble as those controlling core feuds close to the capital ruled by the king.

> 1. 齐侯阳虎，将东之。 from 《左传·定公九年》 http://www.guoxuemeng.com/guoxue/323.html
> 2. 仲子曰：“······今无故而废之，是专黜诸侯，而以难犯不祥也。君必悔之。”公曰：“在我而已。”遂东太子光。 from 《左传·襄公十九年》 http://www.guoxuemeng.com/guoxue/270.html

In both cases, a website gives translation for 东 in modern Chinese that contains a component of 东部边境 which means eastern border regions. See the links above. I am not sure where you found a translation as in 东鄙 which does not help translate. Please comment with a good source of English translation to Chinese classics if you encounter any.

On the other hand, [东夷](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%9C%E5%A4%B7) or [Dong Yi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dongyi) during that time refers the barbaric East then controlled by local tribes who did not report or pay tribute to the king in the capital historically. However, these regions were gradually incorporated by the central dynasty after the king recognized the local rulers through the tribute system, and were soon no longer considered barbaric or despicable. The regions then referred 东夷 cover roughly the province of Shandong and some part of Jiangsu in modern days.

Comment: Haha: if you have money you are no longer barbaric! Thanks for the links, I found the book on 京东 （不是京东鄙！）